# Django: how to exclude model fields to not appear in the database

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

My project has 3 models, one of them is the model "Bike", I want to store the attributes "id", "brand" and "purchase_date" in the database (this is like any other model), but the problem appears when I need to have also the attributes "lock", "battery" and "coordinates" which must not be stored in the database (these 3 attributes will change every 30 sec so makes no sense to be stored in the DB).

I want to do something like this:

DEFAULT_COORDINATES = (41.6522996, -4.7298879)
DEFAULT_BATTERY = 100   # 100%

DEFAULT_LOCK = True     # Locked

class Bike(models.Model):

```
id = models.CharField(max_length=300, primary_key=True)
brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
purchase_date = models.DateField()

lock = DEFAULT_LOCK
battery = DEFAULT_BATTERY
coordinates = DEFAULT_COORDINATES

@property
def lock(self):
    """
    Returns the lock state of the bike. 
    True = Locked
    False = Unlocked

    Returns:
         Boolean: The lock state of the bike.
    """
    return self.lock

@property
def battery(self):
    """
    Returns the battery level of the bike.

    Returns:
         Double: The battery level of the bike.
    """
    return self.battery

@property
def coordinates(self):
    """
    Returns the GPS coordinates of the bike.

    Returns:
         String: The GPS coordinates of the bike.
    """
    return self.coordinates

@lock.setter
def lock(self, lock):
    """
    Sets the lock state of the bike.

    Args:
        lock state (Boolean): 'True' if bike is locked, 'False' otherwise.
    """
    self.lock = lock

@battery.setter
def battery(self, battery):
    """
    Sets the battery level of the bike.

    Args:
        battery (Double): Battery level of the bike.
    """
    self.battery = battery

@coordinates.setter
def coordinates(self, coordinates):
    """
    Sets the coordinates of the bike.

    Args:
        coordinates (Tuple): Tuple containing the latitude and longitude coordinates of the bike.
    """
    self.coordinates = coordinates

def to_json(self):
    """
    Returns the object in JSON format.

    Returns:
        The bike object in JSON format.
    """
    json_dict = {
        "dev_id": self.dev_id,
        "lock": self.lock,
        "battery": self.battery,
        "coordinates": self.coordinates
    }
    return json_dict
```

But this problem appears:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDSt6.png)

In the terminal you can see the attribute "brand" works fine, but the other one "lock" gives an error.

So my question is how could I use those extra attributes to work with them without affecting the database and to be able to obtain their values when working with the backend.

Comment: You can not `return self.lock`, since `self.lock` is the property itself, so you will call the getter when you call the getter... You should use a different name for the internal field. Although here I don't see why you use getters/setters in the first place.

Comment: I use getters and setters because the values change every 30 sec or less, and I can´t use CRUD since those attributes are not supposed to be in the database.

Comment: But just without using getters/setters, you can also use `self.lock = some_value`, etc.

Comment: That's true, thank you very much for the help